# Should I write "solitude" or "a solitude" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, zero-article, countability

Sentence:

> After a few days, the fresh flavor of the food became (a) stale
>   solitude.

I'm a bit confused about the word *solitude*. It sounds countable and non-countable at the same time. So I don't know whether to use an "a" or not.

Comment: The sentence would be grammatical either with or without the "a". However, its meaning is unclear.

Comment: That's a *very* metaphorical sentence!  I, too, would use "a" because food (physical substances that are nourishing when eaten) cannot be solitude (a state of psychological apartness), so it has to be re-cast to be more clearly metaphor.

Comment: I don't think **solitude** works in this context, even as a metaphor.  Do you mean (some variation on) [**solace**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/solace), perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solitude* when used in a countable sense can mean "a time, event, or thing where solitude featured prominently", in an uncountable sense it means "the quality of being alone and uninterrupted."

So it depends on whether you want to equate *flavor* with something that has solitude as a prominent attribute (which would be inferred from context) or equate it with the quality of *solitude* directly.